# Is this site for learners or pundits

Tags: discussion, etiquette, new-users

^ If this site is for *pundits* in English, then Its not place for me. I believe its not *only* for pundits but absolutely for learners:

[*Tour*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) says:

> English Language Learners Stack Exchange is a question and answer site **for speakers of other languages** ***learning English***.

It is clear it's for someone like me.

Here is my issue:
I have asked a [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75223/translation-of-why-for-you-softer-politer-synonyms-for-its-not-your-busin) which got 2 UVs and 1 DV. The question is not worthy to get upvote unless it is edited by some great people (some high rep users edited and made post more clearer). Also, its not worthy to get downvote after such good edit (IMHO).

Importantly, a moderator suggested to edit the title, a high reputation user edited to make it more clear, but an anonymous (sorry, I don't know who) user gave downvote after such clear post (IMO).

*This is one of those things that doesn't take a lot of discussion/belabouring in my opinion*.

But at the same time, it is not the way to welcome a new user, isn't it?

Comment: We say "someone," not "some one." Apart from that, edits are made to make a question more clear. Suppose a new user comes and puts tags which seems appropriate to him/her, but, in fact, it might not be a proper tag. Another instance, suppose a question is not cleat at all, users don't know what an OP is asking, this will likely to get downvotes and getting closed, unless someone else comes along and makes an proper edit(I am not talking about your question, but in general). :)

Comment: "Pundits," not "pandit." and "It's," not "its." I didn't edit your post here so you will understand some minor mistake and learn a thing or two. :) peace out!

Comment: I'll just say this for now: This is a site where learners and pundits help each other out. The site isn't "for" one group or the other, because each group needs the other to make this work.

Comment: Ravan your question doesn't make sense. It's like asking 'who are the apples for?' The apples are for anyone that wants to eat them. Stack Exchange is meant to be an interactive library. If someone doesn't want to use it, they're free not to, and if someone wants to use it *fairly*, no one should stop them from doing so. As for voting, downvotes and upvotes are just indicators of the post's quality. In an ideal world, they should only be aimed at **content**, not **person**. So you can be a pundit, and you can be a learner. You're a mere stranger and your contributions prove who you are.

Comment: @Usernew I have no objection if __someone__ edit my post, I not even bother about that (atleast in this post) :)

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Your comment doesn't makes sense to me tbh. As J.R pointed, this site is for both. I agree. How can you expect super good __content__ from a learner post? His (learner) post need some edits or something to make it more clear (or atleast to get the __content__ which you are saying). It can be done without downvoting, correct?

Comment: @Usernew Please see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandit . Also the so called _Pundit_ originated from pandit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pundit :)

Comment: What part of it do you deem nonsensical? All I'm saying is that SE is meant to  be a source of information ultimately. You may or may not want to use it and that's irrelevant to your being a linguist or a novice learner. And let's make our case clear: Are we talking about why you got downvotes? *Or* if this site's for novices or experts, the answer to which was stated in my previous comment? You're mixing two factors that are irrelevant. A novice learner may come up with a very good and thought-out question, while a rash expert will only confuse the poor learners further with bogus remarks.

Comment: So I understand if you're upset about a downvote, but that's not relevant to your being an advanced learner or beginner, nor to your being a new or veteran user. The only real reason behind the downvote can be explained by the person who downvoted. And you made it clear: "This is one of those things that doesn't take a lot of discussion/belabouring in my opinion."

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. yup, I clearly mentioned the last line to avoid discussions like this. Anyway thank you :)

Comment: @Ravan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandit :)

Comment: I up-vote questions that I think would be valuable to other learners, ask about something that hasn't been answered in another post on the site, and show that the asker has made some effort to try to find an answer or to try to explain the question clearly. It doesn't matter to me if the title is perfect, or the grammar and spelling is good, because that can be easily fixed. I don't down-vote questions very often, just answers. I usually vote to close questions so they can be corrected and re-opened instead of down-voting. Questions that are OK but not great, I don't vote up or down.

Comment: *pundit* is derived from the Sanskrit word *pandit*. Someone ***learned*** in both the languages **know** the difference! :) @Usernew However, in this case, you are right! :)

Comment: Ravan, use *'pandit'* when you mean the one who does 'yagyas' and 'poojas' i.e. a *brahmin*. Use *'pundit'* when you want to call someone 'master' in something.

Comment: Native speakers have no idea about Hindu rituals and know the word *only* for its meaning of 'mastering something'. That's why they think 'pandit' does not exist! Not their fault! :)

Comment: @MaulikV thanks =), I _know_ both English and Sanskrit, that might be the reason, I used the word interchangeably :) I will try to refrain from using it (atleast with native speakers) =)

Comment: @MaulikV I know both the words. :) but like you said, in this case, I am right :)

Comment: I never even read the Vedas.

Answer (score 4):

Upvotes and downvotes are personal opinions. However, in almost all cases, many agree on one point and thus, you see more voting on either of those sides (up or down).

> The question is not worthy to get upvote unless it is edited by some great people (some high rep users edited and made post more clearer).

Not true. Questions get upvotes if **they are worthy, not who asked or edited them.** Yes, editing play some role but then it is only to make the question clearer. At times, the original posters need support to put their concern in appropriate words. This has nothing to do with *great people* or *users with high rep*. I've seen and approved many new users who edit questions *(including my questions!)*.

I suggested to edit the title because you clarified that your concern is to find polite or less severe version of 'none of your business'. The title with *just* 'Why for you' did not serve the purpose then.

Clear titles are important here because ELL is a highly reputed website cached by search engines in a very short period. It comes high on SERPs when you search for any English language question. Imagine these two cases:

The original question as it *may* **appear** on search engine result pages:

> Why for you

I'm not sure *googling* which 'query' would bring that up.

And, after edit...

> Softer, politer synonyms for 'It's none of your business'

This might show in results if people search for alternative, softer version, more polite way to say 'it's none of your business' or queries the like.

And, for this sake, why simply search engines; the new users *do* such searches on ELL as well (a local search).

Better title, easier search, great results!

So, as I see, there are two concerns of yours that I try to answer

> a) *editing* is suggested/done in the interest of the community
>
> b) *editing* a question does not ensure any 'shield' to downvoting. Editing just clarifies the question further with better words, formatting or sentence structure

About [reasons of downvoting](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/413/reasons-for-downvoting/455#455), [why don't users leave comment after downvoting](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/413/reasons-for-downvoting) -they all have been always moot points here.

You may read [J.R.'s answer here.](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/bullying-trolls-lack-of-moderators/1322#1322) You may find it helpful as a new user to this site.

---

I personally find this site for *learners to make them pundit!*

Comment: Well, @Maulik, Here I used the term `great people` but that is not equal to high reputation users (IMO). instead I mean some one. Yes questions get UV if they worthy but I mean, my original post hasn't unless edit.  I appreciate you for suggesting to change title, because I myself felt the title is not a proper one. "the original posters need support to put their concern in appropriate words" yeah, I remember, the edit is after my comment, to provide context which was deleted by mod.

Comment: btw I really like your  last punch line :)

Comment: No problem. Good that you discuss/suggest/ask here before reacting. Personally, I've learned a lot of things here *(not just language!)*. I understand all such concerns like yours because I've been there! Happy learning.